# Rx operator to run tasks in series, gathering exceptions at the end

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, system.reactive

I am using Rx in Silverlight 4 to call my data access code (in absence of place of TPL).

I'd like to make 3 web service calls in series (not parallel for now) and get their results.  I used to use SelectMany:

```cs
var seq = from a1 in Observable.Return(5).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
          from b1 in Observable.Return(6).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
          from c1 in Observable.Return(7).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
          select new { a1, b1, c1 };
```

but I'd like the 2nd and third calls to still be performed even if the first has an exception.

Is there an Rx operator that will combine sequences, but only OnException once all its sequences have completed?  Something that will be functionally equivalent to the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{

    public class Results
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Test();
        }

        public void Test()
        {

            GetResults().SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(
                results => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", results.A, results.B, results.C),
                ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Completed")
            );

            Console.WriteLine("Not blocking");

            Console.Read();
        }

        public IObservable<Results> GetResults()
        {
            return Observable.Create<Results>(obs =>
                {

                    var a = Observable.Return(5).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    var b = Observable.Throw<int>(new Exception("uh oh")).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    var c = Observable.Return("7").Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

                    var results = new Results();
                    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

                    try
                    {
                        results.A = a.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        exceptions.Add(ex);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        results.B = b.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        exceptions.Add(ex);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        results.C = c.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        exceptions.Add(ex);
                    }

                    obs.OnNext(results);
                    if (exceptions.Count > 0)
                        obs.OnError(new AggregateException(exceptions.ToArray()));
                    else
                        obs.OnCompleted();
                    return Disposable.Empty;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var result = Observable.Concat(
    startObservable1().Catch(Observable.Return<TTheType>(null)),
    startObservable2().Catch(Observable.Return<TTheType>(null)),
    startObservable3().Catch(Observable.Return<TTheType>(null)));
```

> Is there an Rx operator that will combine sequences, but only OnException once all its sequences have completed?

This part is a little harder, I use this class though I'm not super happy with it:

```
public class Maybe<T>
{
    public Exception Exception { get; protected set; }

    T _Value;
    public T Value {
        get {
            if (Exception != null) {
                throw Exception;
            }
            return _Value;
        }
        protected set { _Value = value; }
    }

    public static Maybe<T> AsError(Exception ex)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>() {Value = default(T), Exception = ex};
    }

    public static Maybe<T> AsValue(T value)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>() {Value = value};
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var result = Observable.Concat(
    startObservable1().Select(x => Maybe.AsValue(x)).Catch<T1, Exception>(x => Maybe.AsError(x)),
    startObservable2().Select(x => Maybe.AsValue(x)).Catch<T1, Exception>(x => Maybe.AsError(x)),
    startObservable3().Select(x => Maybe.AsValue(x)).Catch<T1, Exception>(x => Maybe.AsError(x)));
```

You could probably write your own Maybeify() Extension Method that hides the Select+Catch.

Comment: I can't use Concat since web services are not returning the same type.  Maybe sounds like a good idea.  It looks like implementing the Task class in SL4.